# Algorithm for quadratic voting in anonymous decentralized systems

Tags: algorithm, electronic-voting

The question is about voting in decentralized systems. [Quadratic voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_voting) is a wonderful way to reach consensus without arranging property qualifications. However, quadratic voting requires a KYC: otherwise, the attacker will simply distribute his funds to many accounts and get many votes, bypassing the quadratic increase in their value (and get linear one).

Question: can a quadratic vote be modified to be used in decentralized systems where all users are anonymous? Are there any other approaches for voting in such systems except the simplest - linear?

Comment: What is a KYC? It would be helpful if you defined or linked to sources of terms.

Comment: So, not just anonymous voting, but anonymous participation in the voting process? And also control a fair and equitable distribution of credits? I'm not sure that would be possible.